# Given a sequence of a function $f_n({x})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $g$ : $ R \rightarrow R$ be a continuous function and let $f_n$ : $R \rightarrow R$ be given by $f_n({x})$ = sin$(x + \frac{g({x})}{n})$ , $x \in R$  for $n=1,2,...$

a) Show that $f_n({x})$  is pointwise convergent as $ n \rightarrow \infty $  for all $x \in R$,  also give the limit function.

I look at $ \frac{g({x})}{n}\rightarrow 0$  as $ n \rightarrow \infty $ then we have sin$(x + 0)$ = sin$(x)$ and finally $f_n \rightarrow $ sin$(x)$. Am I right?

b) Give a reason that for all $y,x \in R$ we say that $ \mid $ sin$({y})-$  sin$({x})$ $ \mid $ $\leq$ $ \mid $ ${y}-$  ${x}$ $ \mid $ and use this to show that the convergence of a) is uniform on a closed and limited interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to $a)$ is correct. Since $\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{g(x)}{n}=0$ and $\sin$ is a continuous function you have that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sin\left(x+\frac{g(x)}{n}\right)=\sin\left(\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(x+\frac{g(x)}{n}\right)\right)=\sin(x+0)=\sin x.$$

The inequality $|\sin y-\sin x|\leq |y-x|$ is a consequence of the mean value theorem for derivatives (note that the derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos,$ which absolute value is bounded by $1$.)

To show uniform convergence on closed and limited intervals, just use the inequality:

$$\left|\sin\left(x+\frac{g(x)}{n}\right)-\sin x \right|\leq \frac{|g(x)|}{n}.$$

Comment: what about c) let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that the sequence $I_n = \int_{a}^{b}$ sin$({x}+ \frac{g({x})}{n}) dx$ is convergent as $n\rightarrow \infty$ and determine the limit value limit $n\rightarrow \infty$ $I_n$ expressed by $a$ and $b$

Comment: The limit is $\int_a^b \sin x dx=\cos a-\cos b.$ To prove it use that $|\int_a^b (\sin(x+\frac{g(x)}{n})-\sin x)dx| \leq \int_a^b |\sin(x+\frac{g(x)}{n})-\sin x|dx.$